# How should I configure my Visual Studio Code launch.json in order for it to show variables and property values?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am new to VSC, after looking through the VSC documentation I admit defeat, I have no Idea how to get the variables panel (left) working. My real concern is that in the "Debugger Console" the object's property and values are not shown, I cannot keep track of what was updated and what wasn't.

My Code:

```
var collection = {
    2548: {
      albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
      artist: 'Bon Jovi',
      tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
    },
    2468: {
      albumTitle: '1999',
      artist: 'Prince',
      tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
    },
    1245: {
      artist: 'Robert Palmer',
      tracks: []
    },
    5439: {
      albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
    }
  };
  

  // Only change code below this line
  function updateRecords(object, id, prop, value) {
    if (value === '') {
      delete object[id][prop];
    }
    else if (prop === 'tracks') {
      object[id][prop] = object[id][prop] || [];
      object[id][prop].push(value);
    } else {
      object[id][prop] = value;
    }
    return object;
   
  }
 
  console.log(updateRecords(collection, 2468, "tracks", "Free"));
```

Expected output(I ran it with node in linux and it works fine):

```
{
  '1245': { artist: 'Robert Palmer', tracks: [] },
  '2468': {
    albumTitle: '1999',
    artist: 'Prince',
    tracks: [ '1999', 'Little Red Corvette', 'Free' ]
  },
  '2548': {
    albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
    artist: 'Bon Jovi',
    tracks: [ 'Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name' ]
  },
  '5439': { albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold' }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set a breakpoint? "No debugger available..." means, that your debugging session already finished, thus you cannot access the variables.

Comment: You are right, now that you mention it I guess I didn't do that before. THank you!

Comment: what about the second part of my question? Do you believe the reason that the debugger console does not show me the full output has anything to do with launch.json? Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: No. The console only logs the output of console.log function. You can access variables while your debugging session is active. To do so, set a breakpoint or use the keyword `debugger` (for test purposes only). You can use the default launch.json which vsc generates for you.